# Number with more than 6 decimals is converted into exponential form

Tags: dataweave

Let me keep it simple

```
Input:
{
  "latitude": 0.0000000,
  "longitude": 0.00000000
}
```

dw code:

```
output application/json
---
{
  location: {
    "lat": payload.latitude,
    "long": payload.longitude
  }
}
```

expected result:

```
{
  location: {
    "lat": 0.00000000,
    "long": 0.00000000
  }
}
```

actual result :

```
{
  location: {
    "lat": 0E-8,
    "long": 0E-8
  }
}
```

Also,

The code works fine for input other than 0.00000000. I observed that it converts the number to exponential if decimals are greater than 6 digits and all the digits are 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is really that you seem to be requiring that JSON numbers to have a specific format. JSON doesn't define format for numbers. Also take into account that some things are left open to the implementation, like precision and limits for representing numbers. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6 or https://www.json.org/json-en.html for some specs.

My understanding is that for any reasonable JSON implementation to be interoperable then 0.00000000 and 0E-8 should be accepted equally but you should not expect to be able to select one format over another. I'm not sure why it doesn't output just 0. It should be accepted as the same value too.

Answer (score 0):

`payload.latitude as String {“format”:”0.0000000”}` and you could output it as application/java

Updating with the json object

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
  location: {
    "lat": payload.latitude as String {"format":"0.0000000"},
    "long": payload.longitude as String {"format":"0.0000000"}
  }
```

Comment: I need to pass it as json object to other api

Comment: again, the format is now changed to String. I wanted is number